# /etc/apt/preferences file is missing

Tags: apt

I should pinning and set priority to Ubuntu repository for installing Kolab mail server. I just added the following to sources.list,

```
deb http://mirror.kolabsys.com/pub/ubuntu/kolab-3.0/ precise release updates
deb-src http://mirror.kolabsys.com/pub/ubuntu/kolab-3.0/ precise release updates
```

but for adding

```
Package: *
Pin: origin mirror.kolabsys.com
Pin-Priority: 501
```

I can not find any "preferences" file in `/etc/apt/`. I searched in Google a lot, but I didn't find anythings. Even in the "preferences.d" directory there is not any "preferences" file. 
I should mention that I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

**How can I make the `/etc/apt/preferences` file?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default there is no `/etc/apt/preferences` file.

You can create it with a user who has `sudo` access:

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/preferences
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences
<PASTE THE PINNING DATA IN>
```

Comment: May i ask another question?!! What does the following command do "cat /etc/apt/preferences"?

Comment: The `cat` command simply "echos" the data from the file, and the `cat` command on its own will simply return the information in the file to the command line's output so you see it.  If the file doesn't exist, it will error out.